# How to make it so that a button can't be clicked until a text box has words in it?

Tags: swift, button

So I have this so far

```
{
    nextNounOutlet.enabled = false
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textfieldNoun.text != "" {
      nextNounOutlet.enabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

I want to make it so that the nextNounOutlet button can't be clicked until something has been put into the text box, but it won't work. This way, it will stay disable forever. I've tried adding else statements, but that won't work and changing the true and false around won't work either.
Any suggestions, i'm using swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)'s answer should work for you, if it doesn't you can re-approach the problem programmatically.

In ViewDidLoad you can add targets to your textFields:

```
 self.firstNameField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
 self.lastNameField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

Then create an action:

```
func textFieldChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    // simple validation
    if firstNameField.text?.characters.count > 0
        && lastNameField.text?.characters.count > 0 {
            self.createButton.enabled = true // re-enable your button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the code so that it is not a "one way street": currently, once `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method disables the button, there is nothing in your code to re-enable it.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Get the text after applying the update
    var txtAfterUpdate:NSString = self.textfieldNoun.text as NSString
    txtAfterUpdate = txtAfterUpdate.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    // Enable or disable the button based on the length of the updated text
    nextNounOutlet.enabled = (txtAfterUpdate.length != 0)
}
```

Comment: You're too fast! Haha. Great answer.

Comment: For projectSearchTxtFld.text should replace that with the name of the text field?

Comment: @RishiPanthee That's right, it was a copy/paste error. Thanks!

Comment: It still doesn't work. I can get it to run, but even after putting text into the textbox, the button is disabled.

Comment: @RishiPanthee That's odd. Could you try adding `NSLog` statement to print the new values of `nextNounOutlet.enabled` and `txtAfterUpdate` expressions, and see if the method is getting called and produces the values that you expect?